# Compose a function odd ( ) that takes three bool arguments and returns True if an odd number of arguments are True and False otherwise

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am confused to what exactly I am being asked so I may be out of the ball park with what I have. Any help is greatly appreciated

```
def odd(1,2,3):
if 1 or 3:
    return True
if 0 or 2:
    return False
```

Comment: Your code is syntactically incorrect. You cannot declare a function like that. Here is some help: `def odd(arg1, arg2, arg3)`. Something like that. You want to then see which arguments are `True`. If the number of `True` arguments is odd, then you return `True`, `False` otherwise.

Comment: You might be interested in the exclusive-or operator `^`; `a ^ b` is `True` if an odd number of `a` and `b` is `True` (that is, either `a` or `b` is `True` but not both).

Comment: @idjaw What im having trouble is getting my head around having it be true for an odd number and false if not. If im using arg1,arg2,arg3. Would i have to say like arg1 and3 are true and arg2 is false?

Comment: A useful note on coming up with your own solution: `bool` is a subclass of `int`, and actual `bool` values are mathematically equivalent to `0` (`False`) and `1` (`True`). So summing your inputs and testing if the result is odd is a reasonable solution.

Comment: @BigMan_13 No. The question is telling you that the function is going to take boolean arguments. So, your function can be called like `odd(True, False, True)`. In this example, you have two `True` arguments being passed, which is an even number of `True`. Therefore, should return `False`, since it is not odd. If your function was called as `odd(True, False, False)`. You now have an odd number of `True` being passed, therefore it will return `True`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to the question, your function receives 3 inputs of type bool, that is they can be `True` or `False`. so what you will want to do is xor them together like this:

```
def odd(par1, par2, par3):
    return par1 ^ par2 ^ par3
```

why xor? you should read up a bit on boolean algebra.
in short though, xoring 3 bools will return true only if the number of True values is odd

the way you use it is:

```
if odd(x,y,z):
    print 'odd'
else:
    print 'even'
```

Comment: would I then print odd?

Comment: Other options: `(par1 != par2) != par3` and (for arbitrary argument count) `def odd(*args): return bool(sum(args) & 1)`. I was surprised to learn that `bool ^ bool` actually returns a new `bool`, not just an equivalent `int`. Python is being nice here. :-)

Comment: @BigMan_13: Utility functions usually don't `print`, they `return` the answer, and it's on the caller (the `main` method driving everything) to determine if it should be printed, or just used as part of the code logic with no output.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks. I am sorry if this is a dumb question, but what do i need to do to make it say if its true or false?

Comment: @BigMan_13 test if the function returns `True`, if it does, print 'odd' otherwise its even

Comment: @Nullman [def odd(par1, par2, par3):
    return par1 ^ par2 ^ par3
if par1 == par3:
    return True
else:
    print False]